# Trying to extract frames from a video where faces are detected using my trained TensorFlow model but it writes black images. What went wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, training-data, face-detection

I'm trying to make a TensorFlow face detection model. One file trains the model and exports the model in a .h5 file shown here.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

image_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10

def load_widerface_dataset(widerface_dir):
    images_dir = os.path.join(widerface_dir, 'WIDER_train', 'images')
    labels_file = os.path.join(widerface_dir, 'wider_face_split', 'wider_face_train_bbx_gt.txt')

    X = []
    y = []

    with open(labels_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    num_images = int(lines[1])
    current_line = 2

    for _ in range(num_images):
        image_path = os.path.join(images_dir, lines[current_line - 2].strip())
        num_faces = int(lines[num_images])

        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image = image.resize((224, 224))
        X.append(np.array(image))

        faces = []
        for i in range(num_faces):
            face_line = lines[current_line + i].strip().split(' ')
            face = [int(coord) for coord in face_line[:4]]
            faces.append(face)

        y.append(np.array(faces))

        current_line += num_faces

        if current_line < len(lines) and not lines[current_line].strip():
            current_line += 1

    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    return X, y

def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                               input_shape=(image_size[0], image_size[1], 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    return model

widerface_dir = 'C:/face_training/WIDER_train'
X_train, y_train = load_widerface_dataset(widerface_dir)
model = build_model()
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)
model.save('face_detection_model.h5')
```

Another file is to take a video and analyze the video using my trained model here and extract frames where faces are detected. Here is the code for it.

```
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import sys
import numpy as np

vidPath = "testclip2.mp4"
model_path = 'face_detection_model.h5'
model = load_model(model_path)

test_tensorflow = 'C:/Users/user/Documents/PyCharmProjects/test_tensorflow'
if not os.path.exists(test_tensorflow):
    os.makedirs(test_tensorflow)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidPath)

currentFrame = 0
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = frame / 255.0
        frames = [frame]

        for frame in frames:
            prediction = model.predict(frame.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3))

            if prediction.any() > 0.5:
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(test_tensorflow, str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'), frame)
                currentFrame += 1

    else:
        break

cap.release()
sys.exit(0)
```

And now I have this problem where the program only extracts black images. I'm not sure what went wrong and I've tried reading up a bunch of stuff but nothing seemed to work. Would really appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are normalising the RGB values, i.e. converting from from a range of 0-255 to a range of 0-1.

This is common practice for modelling and predicting, but when you try to output the result with OpenCv it will not understand the normalised pixel values.

You can try a quick fix suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165573/334402

This essentially just restores the original 0-255 range that OpenCV is expecting.